# Как отобразить на веб-страничке только нужную часть файла?

Tags: java

Есть текстовый файл, в котором есть несколько строк которые нужно отобразить в веб-интерфейсе,  сам файл лежит на диске, нужно прочитать файл от одного символа (прим. `local`) до другого (прим. `}`).

Каким методом пользоваться (`indexof`, `RandomAccessFile` или др.?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `RandomAccessFile` есть метод:

```
public void seek(long pos);
```

с помощью которого осуществляется позиционирование в файле.

В решении Вашей задачи класс `RandomAccessFile` Вам не поможет, так как Вы заранее не знаете позиции начального и конечного символов (или же строк).

Для решения Вашей задачи можно использовать классы `FileReader`, `BufferedReader` и метод `indexOf(...)` класса `String`:

```
String text = null;
try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    text = stringBuilder.toString();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

int p1 = text.indexOf("a");
int p2 = text.indexOf("b", p1);
if (p1 != -1 && p2 != -1) {
    String neededText = text.substring(p1, p2+1);
    System.out.println(neededText);
} else {
    System.out.println("Smth going wrong!");
}
```

В результате выполнения этого кода, в переменной `neededText` Вы получите часть содержимого файла `file.txt` от символа (строки) `a` до символа (строки) `b`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!